# Import source code from Overleaf in Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, overleaf, sourcecode

I have downloaded the source code from the "Overleaf" of my thesis project. Now I want to edit and work on it with a local TeX editor, e.g. TexStudio or Texmaker. The source code contains these following files (In the attached graphics).

[image: my setup]

In the main folder, there are additional 7 folders, each containing .tex files for different chapters and abstract and appendix.

How can I load the whole project in TexStudio or Texmaker? I have tried several times but failed. I would appreciate it if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't know about TeXstudio, but as for Texmaker, you only need to open the main .tex file of your project and compile this, since everthing else should be embedded or linked from there. There is no need to import the whole project and, as far as I know, Texmaker does not provide such a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: You don't need to import anything into TeXstudio. Just unpack the source and you're good to go.

TeXstudio only serves as an editor for your `.tex` (+ `.bib`, `.sty`, etc.) files and viewer for the PDF.
As long as the relative location of all the files is the same on your computer as it was on Overleaf, the same code should compile the same way. All that really matters is that you let the compiler know that stuff located in 'Main' is in `./Main/` (as you needed to on Overleaf too).

If you have organized everything correctly, TeXstudio also displays the other files of your project in the structure on the left, from where you can open them from within the editor (they're red here, because I didn't create the files for this answer):

[image]

One way you could think about this is, when switching from Overleaf to an offline editor, the editor replaces everything right of the red line, while your file explorer substitutes the left part (and your LaTeX distribution handles the stuff you can't see on Overleaf).

[image]